# Graphite / Grafana - fetch metrics, aggregate, store as a new metric - any solution?

Tags: graphite, grafana, statsd

I've got fairly specific use case where I need to multiply:

- metric A by metric B, let's call it AB
- metric C by metric D, let's call it CD
  and so on

Then I need to use `AB`, `CD` ... `YZ` together in order to work out result, let's call it `ABYZ`. The real transformations are more complicated, but let's skip it as it's not that important.

It would make my life easier if I have the `AB` and `CD` precalculated, as I could query it using template variables in Grafana. 
Let's say I could specify variable `$include` which would be list of pairs: `AB`, `CD` etc. 
Then I could easily control the results for `ABYZ` by including some of the metrics and excluding some of them.

In my current schema, without metrics being precalculated, it's not possible to use template variables, as at this stage is not possible to work out which metric should by multiplied by which metric.

Let's say I would like to get the results of this Graphite query:
     alias(diffSeries(maxSeries(multiplySeries(maxSeries(stats.gauges.stock.{stock1,stock2}.offers.*EUR*.bid.*), averageSeries(stats.gauges.stock.currency.fidor.*.EUR.PLN)),maxSeries(stats.gauges.stock.{stock1,stock2}.offers.*PLN*.bid.*)), minSeries(multiplySeries(minSeries(stats.gauges.stock.{stock1,stock2}.offers.*EUR*.ask.*), averageSeries(stats.gauges.stock.currency.fidor.*.EUR.PLN)),minSeries(stats.gauges.stock.{stock1,stock2}.offers.*PLN*.ask.*))), 'diff')

and store it in this metrics: `stats.gauges.stock.diff`

Is there any solution which could create new metrics from existing ones? I would like skip StatsD layer and touch the `graphite` / `carbon` layer directly (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely write a small script that can query the values A, B, etc from graphite and feed AB, etc into carbon so you can query them back out from graphite.

Pretty much any language should suffice, the graphite API is just JSON over HTTP and the carbon protocol is even simpler.  Here's a small PHP script I wrote a while back to get values from my home automation system and feed them into carbon after doing some transformations.  It is just run via cron on an appropriate interval.  The only difference for your application would be that you're pulling the raw values from graphite rather than from an external system.

https://gist.github.com/DanCech/348d37ee45898b34abd3

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Initially I wasn't sure how to reliably do that, but now after testing writes to `carbon` directly I can see that it's also possible to fill in points in the past. Similar script to yours running periodically with the one off initial run (to calculate all the historical data) and I should be fine. All the best !